# Joda-Time Hibernate PersistentYearMonthDay Deprecated

Tags: hibernate, jodatime

In looking through the Joda-Time Hibernate [user guide](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/userguide.html) it appears that there is no future support for the SQL DATE type.  Since TIMESTAMP is specified to start on Jan 1, 1970 - the only safe transport for dates before 1970 appears to be VARCHAR with PersistentLocalTimeAsString (if one wishes to restrict themselves to the Joda Hibernate library).

As someone who uses DATE (and seeing that Joda Hibernate isn't) I am wondering if there is some reason I should switch to VARCHAR and PersistentLocalTimeAsString.  Ie. what motivated the decision to deprecate PersistentYearMonthDay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't start on 1970, it's a zero point, but it could be negative. The reason why the `PersistentYearMonthDay` deprecated is deprecation of [`YearMonthDay`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/YearMonthDay.html). Motivated as "*Use LocalDate which has a much better internal implementation and has been available since 1.3*"

Also, it's weird, but [the source code](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/apidocs/src-html/org/joda/time/contrib/hibernate/PersistentLocalDate.html) for the PersistentLocalDate has `DATE` sql type, while the user guide says `TIMESTAMP`, try it, maybe just a typo in the user guide.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't checked the source.  Surprise, so sql DATE is supported :-)  Funny, I had always assumed that timestamps were unsigned integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
long someTimeBefore1970 = -83688769L;
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(someTimeBefore1970);
System.out.println(ts);
```

The 0 is set to the 1st Jan. 1970, but that doesn't mean that dates before aren't supported.

Comment: Good point.  Oddly enough the MySQL doc gives the 'range' for TIMESTAMP as '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07'.