# Mapping a date, without time, in Joda/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, date

I was looking at [this page](http://www.joda.org/joda-time-hibernate/userguide.html) in order to get an alternate class than `java.util.Date` for `DATE` columns in my Hibernate mapping.

I found that no one of the non-outdated types map to a `DATE` column in SQL.

I want to ask what is the Joda type that maps to SQL `DATE`.

Additional info: we are considering Joda as we are having troubles using `java.util.Date` to represent a date without time because if client and server's time zones don't match the date may get a day earlier. There are plenties of questions/issues open right now. To be precise: if client is in a positive time zone and server speaks UTC or a negative time zone.

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307593/joda-time-hibernate-persistentyearmonthday-deprecated, you want PersistentLocalDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I use EclipseLink for persistence, I never used Joda-Time-Hibernate before.

Instead, to map Joda types, I always use a standard JPA [`@Convert`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html) to map them to the database.

For example, a simple, straight-forward converter could look like this:

```
@Converter
public class LocalDateToDateConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date>
{
   @Override
   public Date convertToDatabaseColumn( LocalDate attribute )
   {
      return attribute == null ? null : new Date( attribute.toDate().getTime() );
   }

   @Override
   public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute( Date dbData )
   {
      return dbData == null ? null : LocalDate.fromDateFields( dbData );
   }

}
```

If you definitely need the column to be a `DATE` and there's no other way, you could give it a try.